# Notificação quando recebo mensagem em segundo plano

Tags: android-notification

Estou desenvolvendo um app que clientes e motoristas logam, eu queria que quando meu app rodasse em segundo plano e quando um cliente enviasse uma mensagem, o motorista recebesse uma notificação, todos os dados estão em um banco online e o sistema e login, cadastro etc já está ok, então, como eu faço pra saber se recebi a mensagem em segundo plano e mostrar que recebi pro motorista.

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buscar_motorista);

    showProgress(true);

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();


    if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                url = ip;

                parametros = "mensagem=buscar";

                new SolicitaDados().execute(url);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nenhuma conexão foi detectada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        login.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        login.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                login.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        login.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        login.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

private class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected  String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametros);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {

        mensagem= resultado;

    }
```

No código acima no oncreate ele faz a requisição e no onPostExecute ele cata o resultado e bota tudo na string

Comment: Como você está recebendo essa mensagem no app?

Comment: Eu coloquei quando o motorista abre o app ele faz a requisição e recebe uma lista de mensagens se caso ela exista no banco, mas eu queria q ele fizesse essa requisição em tempos em tempos em segundo plano

Comment: Pronto, botei a parte do código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso você não esteja utilizando o **[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)** ou outro banco de dados realtime, recomendo utiliza-los.

Dessa forma você receberá alterações no banco de dados no momento em que elas ocorrerem. Isso evitará delay desnecessários e economizará bateria.

---

Caso ainda sim você queira utilizar um banco de dados em seu servidor. Você poderá utilizar alguns **[serviços de agendamento](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html)**, como por exemplo o **[AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)** (Lollipop ou inferior) ou **[JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)** (Lollipop ou superior) para agendar tarefas no seu app.

**Exemplo com JobSchedule (Verificações a cada 1 minuto)**

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, checkMessageJobService.class);

JobInfo jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(context)
   .setBackoffCriteria(60*1000, BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
   .setRequiredNetworkType(NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
   .build();

JobSchedule jobSchedule = (JobSchedule) context.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
jobSchedule.schedule(jobInfo);
```

**checkMessageJobService.java**

```
public class checkMessageJobService extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {

        /* Aqui você faz sua requisição com AsyncTask */

        // Retorne true para o serviço ser reagendado conforme o método setBackoffCriteria
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

O código acima executará a cada 1 minuto aproximadamente. Dessa forma você poderá executar as requisições para verificação se há novas mensagens.

---

**Exemplo com AlarmManager (Verificações a cada 1 minuto)**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, checkMessageReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

if (alarmManager != null) {
    alarmManager.setRepeating(ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
}
```

**checkMessageReceiver.java**

```
public class checkMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /* Faça sua requisição aqui */
    }
}
```

O código acima executará a cada 1 minuto. Dessa forma você poderá executar as requisições para verificação se há novas mensagens.

---

**Exibindo notificação**

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "NewMessage")
        .setContentTitle("Nova mensagem de Fulano")
        .setContentInfo("Já está no caminho?")
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (notificationManager != null) {
    notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);
}
```

Comment: Esse atualização de 1 em 1 minuto ocorre mesmo em segundo plano? E se não, como eu deixo o app ligado em segundo plano e fazendo essa atualização?

Comment: Ocorre em segundo plano sim. Segundo a própria documentação: `O AlarmManager destina-se a casos em que você deseja que seu código de aplicativo seja executado em um horário específico, mesmo que seu aplicativo não esteja sendo executado.`

Comment: No caso do JobSchedule, ele irá executar o servidor independente do app está em background ou não. No exemplo que coloquei, basta que o dispositivo tenha acesso a internet para ele executar o serviço indicado.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, vou implementar aqui mas creio que dará certo, obrigado msm

Comment: @ValdeirPsr cara, no exemplo do JobSchedule, onde adicione a primeira parte do código? Criei a class, mas a primeira parte não sei onde adiciono

Comment: @ValdeirPsr o erro ocorre nessa linha:  checkMessageJobService jobSchedule = (checkMessageJobService) this.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

Comment: @WotonSampaio Qual o erro? Pode ser adicionado na activity, adapter etc.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr eu mexi aqui e funcionou, porém, ele só executa uma unica vez, vc saberia me dizer qual seria o possível problema?

Comment: Você está utilizando `Alarm` ou `Job`? Em qual versão do Android você está testando?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr O job, estou usando a versão 7.0

Comment: @WotonSampaio Na API 24, utilize [setPeriodic](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPeriodic) com o `flexMillis`. Verifique também no `LogCat`, em versões mais recente do Android, ele limite o tempo mínimo entre 5 e 15 minutos.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr então n é possivel o fazer com menos d 5 minutos? Só no minimo de 5 em 5?

Comment: @WotonSampaio Eu ainda não testei de um em um minutos. Se você deseja uma precisão, utilize o `AlarmManager`. Como disse na resposta, o `JS` é um tempo aproximado. Mas irei tentar testar e te retorno algo

Comment: @ValdeirPsr obrigado, vou aguardar